# Different title for each subplot in 2 x 2 Seaborn

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to display a 2 x 2 Seaborn plot of histograms.

I want a different title for each subplot.

This runs without error, and creates the desired 2 x 2 matrix of subplots, but all four subplots have the same title (the last item in the list 'titles'):

```
titles = ['SAT Participation Rates 2017 Distribution',
          'ACT Participation Rates 2017 Distribution',
          'SAT Participation Rates 2018 Distribution',
          'ACT Participation Rates 2018 Distribution']

cols = ['sat_participation_17',
        'act_participation_17',
        'sat_participation_18',
        'act_participation_18']

f, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(10, 10))
for ax, feature in zip(axes.flat, df[cols]):
    sns.distplot(df[feature], bins=8, kde=False, hist_kws={'edgecolor': 'black'}, ax=ax)
    ax.set_xlabel('Participation Rate')
    ax.set_ylabel('Frequency')
    for title in titles:
        ax.set_title(title)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
count = 0
for ax, feature in zip(axes.flat, df[cols]):
    sns.distplot(df[feature], bins=8, kde=False, hist_kws={'edgecolor': 'black'}, ax=ax)
    ax.set_xlabel('Participation Rate')
    ax.set_ylabel('Frequency')
    ax.set_title(titles[count])
    count+=1
```

The problem in your code is that the inner for loop is repeated at each outer loop iteration, and thus the title is always sets as the last item in the list `titles`.